# How to have many print statements in a project but selectively choose what prints?

Tags: python

I am looking for something similar to how logcat works for android development.
In android dev when you are printing to the terminal/logging, the function you call takes a tag and the message to print. That tag can then be used in the logcat terminal to filter what output you see.

Is there something similar(in-built/library/module/script) in python where at the start of a program you can give a set of tags that should print and any print statements with tags not in the set do not get printed?

I have looked at the in built logging and log level stuff that python provides and I don't think it has what I need but maybe someone else could enlighten me to what I don't see.

As a quick example, something like this:

```
class TagLog():
tag_set = set()

def log(tag, logMsg):
    if isinstance(tag, str) and isinstance(logMsg, str):
        if tag in TagLog.tag_set:
            print(logMsg)

def add_tag(tag):
    if isinstance(tag, str):
        TagLog.tag_set.add(tag)

def add_set(tag_set):
    if isinstance(tag_set, set):
        TagLog.tag_set.update(tag_set)

def remove_tag(tag):
    if isinstance(tag, str):
        TagLog.tag_set.discard(tag)
```

Comment: Why not just grep in the full log output?

Comment: B/c that adds an added step to what I am doing. I am looking for a solution that would work for my development flow that does not add steps to the iterative process.

Comment: Could you clarify why you don't think logging meets your needs?

Comment: Logging does not offer a fine grain easy approach. I don't want to set logging to debug and then have all debug messages to sift through. I want to be able to pass in a list of tags to what ever I am using and then at that runtime it prints/logs the things I want at that time. If I use the in-built logging then I would have many log messages using level debug and would have to comment these in and out all over the place, depending on the task I am working on.

Comment: `log(tag, logMsg) == logging.getLogger(tag).info()`. You can configure each tag-specific logger independently.

Comment: You also have the flexibility of adding multiple handlers (each of which could simply write to standard output) to each logger, and each handler has its *own* level that can be configured independently of the level of the logger the handler is attached to. (Basically `logger.info(...)` will invoke handlers at all if the logger is configured to emit info-level messages, and each handler will only output if *it* is configured to handle info-level messages).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to use is the Python `logging` [built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

Here's a very basic example, taken from the Python documentation:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')
```

By changing the value of the `level` parameter passed to `logging.basicConfig` to a different constant value from the logging module, such as `logging.WARNING` or `logging.CRITICAL`, any messages of a lower priority will be skipped.

By default, logging messages will print to stdout, but it can be configured to log to a file instead.  If you are using multiple modules, you can setup logging configuration in the main script, and any logging calls in the imported modules will use that same configuration.

Comment: That is not what I want. This solution would mean that in my projects all log messages of debug will print. I don't want to have to comment in and out log/print messages. I want to be able to give a print/log message a set of tags and then on runtime you set what tags get printed. You then can have one place that you make changes and can then run the project.

With this given solution I would still need to go to multiple files and comment log messages in and out depending on the task I am working on.

Comment: You use different loggers (instances of the `Logger` class), not just the root logger implicitly used by the module-level functions. Each one can be configured differently, and that configuration can be read from an external file, not just hard-coded in the script itself.

Comment: Maybe what you want to use is `logging.Filters()`?  
 Then you can change which loggers can pass through the filter.   
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Filter   Alternatively, you can effectively turn off a logger by setting its level to `logging.CRITCAL+1`

Comment: There may be a solution that is a combination of @chepner, OP, and my examples code. Simple front end that then programmatically calls all the needed logging stuff to get what I want. Will have to look at further.